# Tiled Android CardViews that are always perfectly square

Tags: c#, xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on the home screen of my app and want to show tiled card views that are always squared with 3 on a row like this...

[image]

This was designed in figma this is not a screenshot of what I have currently.

So I want it to look like that but I want all the squares to be equal whatever the screen size. I tried doing this with a GridLayout however I am not sure how I should control the height to make is the same size as the width of the card.

Comment: I do not like the buildin Layout control because it is limited what you can do with it.  I usually use a main panel and then add my own child panels to the main panel in a grid.  You can control the location of the child panels by using the Top and Left Position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do this in your native Xamarin.Android app,

**[Support libraries](https://blog.xamarin.com/mastering-android-support-libraries/) are a pre-requisite for this solution**

How I like to do it is using the support library [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout), you can download it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.GridLayout/)

Then in your XML or AXML add it as follows:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true"
            app:columnCount="2"   
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/BoxMainGridLayout"
            android:background="@color/colorBackgroundHomeGrey">
```

Here column count is the number of columns you want in your Grid so change it as per your requirement.

Also, add the res-auto xml namespace to your layout file something like this:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Once you're done with this you can either add this layout's children from code or XML.

**Code:**

```
using Gridlayout = Android.Support.V7.Widget.GridLayout; // use namespace
private Gridlayout ParentGrid; // Global field
```

Reference the GridLayout:

```
ParentGrid = view.FindViewById<Gridlayout>(Resource.Id.BoxMainGridLayout);
```

Then add a ViewGroup or a View in it something like this

```
ParentGrid.AddView(BoxLayout); // This can be any type of view
```

**Note** the children should have column and row weight set using layout params like the eg below:

```
        Button BoxLayout= new Button(**Activity reference**);
        Gridlayout.LayoutParams param = new Gridlayout.LayoutParams(Gridlayout.InvokeSpec(Gridlayout.Undefined, 1f), Gridlayout.InvokeSpec(Gridlayout.Undefined, 1f))
        {
            Height = 0,
            Width = 0
        };
        button.LayoutParameters = (param);
```

**XML:**

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true"
            app:columnCount="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/BoxMainGridLayout"
            android:background="@color/colorBackgroundHomeGrey">
      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/package_margin_layout"
                android:padding="@dimen/package_padding_layout"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                  android:background="@color/colorWhiteBackground"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/layoutBox2">
       </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/package_margin_layout"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorWhiteBackground"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="@dimen/package_padding_layout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/layoutBox3">
          </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Hope this helps revert in case of queries

**Update**

In your Activity context get display metrics :

```
var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
var displayWidth= metrics.WidthPixels;
```

Once you have the width then you need to decide how many squares do you want and how much margin padding are you adding so that you decide the proper height :

Eg: if you want two squares you get the width with the above code after that remove the margin padding that you have defined in XML from your total width to and then divide the width to get height.

```
var exactWidth= displayWidth - pxFromDp(this,10); //Assuming the sum of margin padding is 10
```

Where pxFromDp is as givenBelow:

```
public static float pxFromDp(Context context, float dp)
{
   return dp * context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
}
```

Once you have this you can get the height of the square as follows:

```
var height= exactWidth/2;  //Where 2 is the number of boxes you have in one column
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need to make sure they are all square but fill the space on screen. I have set the weights of the cards but how do i decide the height and width of each card

Comment: different devices have different sizes how do you plan on setting height width so that it works on all screens?

Comment: i will plan for the width of the grid layout to match_parent but i dont know how to do height so that i always get a perfect square

Comment: See its simpler than you think what you can do is get the width using display metrics  then use this width and calculate the height will update my code in sometime